# PHP echos Out of Order

Tags: php, mysql, json

I wrote a script in PHP that takes values from a MySQL Database and outputs the values as JSON. However, I'm having a problem. Here's the code:

```
    <?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("stitchdex");
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT image, price, description FROM {$_GET['table']}");
    $jsonString = "{\"images\":[";
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $i=0;
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) ) {
        $jsonString .= "{\"image\":\"{$row['image']}\", \"price\":\"{$row['price']}\", \"description\":\"{$row['description']}\"}";
        if ( ($numrows-1) == $i ) echo "";
        else echo ",";
        $i++;
    }
    $jsonString .= "]}";
    echo $jsonString;
?>
```

But it outputs:

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,{"images":[{"image":"priceguide1.jpg", "price":"", "description":"Diagram of Options"}{"image":"2ndamendfront.jpg", "price":"$109.00", "description":"Total of 3 laser etchings"}{"image":"DSC_0120.jpg", "price":"$99.00", "description":"Designer Kydex 1 Laser Etching"}{"image":"DSC_0121.jpg", "price":"", "description":"Lazer Etching on Back"}{"image":"gilbert.jpg", "price":"$109.00", "description":"Designer Kydex 2 Lazer Etchings"}{"image":"glock23-carbonfiber-red1.jpg", "price":"$79.00", "description":""}{"image":"irish1.jpg", "price":"$129.00", "description":"Designer Kydex Two Tone Leather & 3 Laser Etchings Two on front One on Back"}{"image":"irish2.jpg", "price":"$129.00", "description":"Designer Kydex Two Tone Leather & 3 Laser Etchings Two on front One on Back"}{"image":"klover-glock-2.jpg", "price":"$129.00", "description":"Designer Kydex Two Tone Leather & 3 Laser Etchings Two on front One on Back"}{"image":"priceguide1.jpg", "price":"", "description":"Diagram of Options"}{"image":"2ndamendfront.jpg", "price":"$109.00", "description":"Total of 3 laser etchings"}{"image":"DSC_0120.jpg", "price":"$99.00", "description":"Designer Kydex 1 Laser Etching"}{"image":"DSC_0121.jpg", "price":"", "description":"Lazer Etching on Back"}{"image":"gilbert.jpg", "price":"$109.00", "description":"Designer Kydex 2 Lazer Etchings"}{"image":"glock23-carbonfiber-red1.jpg", "price":"$79.00", "description":""}{"image":"irish1.jpg", "price":"$129.00", "description":"Designer Kydex Two Tone Leather & 3 Laser Etchings Two on front One on Back"}{"image":"irish2.jpg", "price":"$129.00", "description":"Designer Kydex Two Tone Leather & 3 Laser Etchings Two on front One on Back"}{"image":"klover-glock-2.jpg", "price":"$129.00", "description":"Designer Kydex Two Tone Leather & 3 Laser Etchings Two on front One on Back"}]}
```

This would be valid JSON if the commas separated the objects in the "images" array, but for some reason the script outputs all of the commas first. Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest don't build a json string by hand, use `json_encode()` for that, thats why it's there for this reason.

```
$data = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode(array('images' => $data));
```

Sidenote: Also, use the improved extension which is mysqli or PDO, and utilize prepared statements. Your present code is directly using `$_GET` variables on the query and is vulnerable to sql injections. Bind them to produce safer queries.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using echo inside the loop, that outputs the commans:

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("stitchdex");
$query = mysql_query("SELECT image, price, description FROM {$_GET['table']}");
$jsonString = "{\"images\":[";
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
$i=0;
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) ) {
    $jsonString .= "{\"image\":\"{$row['image']}\", \"price\":\"{$row['price']}\", \"description\":\"{$row['description']}\"}";
    if ( ($numrows-1) == $i ) echo ""; //<--- echo empty string? why?
    else echo ","; //<--- HERE YOU ECHO THE COMMAS
    $i++;
}
$jsonString .= "]}";
echo $jsonString; //<--- AND THEN HERE YOU ECHO EVERYTHING ELSE
?>
```

Concatenate them to `$jsonString` instead.

---

Try this code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $jsonString .= "{\"image\":\"{$row['image']}\", \"price\":\"{$row['price']}\", \"description\":\"{$row['description']}\"}";
    if (($numrows-1) != $i)
    {
        $jsonString .= ",";
    }
    $i++;
}
$jsonString .= "]}";
echo $jsonString;
```

---

By the way mysql_* functions are obsolete.

---

PS: I aprove [Ghost's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26051028/402022) - my intention with this answer is to help you understand what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you are echoeing commas before the json string.
Change

```
else echo ",";
```

to

```
 $jsonString .= ", ";
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the output that you want, you may do:

```
$data = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) ) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
$arr['images'] = $data;
echo json_encode($arr);
```